# Ordering lists in Nav bar spacing

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am currently trying to make a nav bar for my website. I am using lists to do so and am having trouble ordering it correctly.

im trying to have the name of my site hanging to the left, 3 lists in the middle and then one hanging to the right.

I am able to get my three in the center correctly but cant get the outside two lists.

Is there a way to space out the lists differently such as adding blank space?

Here is an example of what I have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/DnvLt/2/

Heres my code:

```
#navbar ul { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 5px; 
list-style-type: none; 
text-align: center; 
background-color: #000;
} 

#navbar ul li {  
display: inline; 
} 

#navbar ul li a { 
text-decoration: none; 
padding: .2em 1em; 
color: #fff; 
background-color: #000; 
} 

#navbar ul li a:hover { 
color: #000; 
background-color: #fff; 
}
```

Comment: Add a fiddle please - That way we can also see the markup and help you :D

Comment: You didn't add the 2nd list or the name :D

Comment: Okay I added them but I dont know how to add the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
<ul style="overflow:hidden; list-style-type: none;">
    <li style="float:left;">Left</li>
    <li style="float:right;">Right</li>
    <li style="overflow:hidden; display:block; width:300px; margin:0 auto;">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
            <li style="float:left;">element 1</li>
            <li style="float:left;">element 2</li>
            <li style="float:left;">element 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

At first you wrap all elements in one block (the div), then you place the right and left elements by float and lastly you place the center element statically in the center on top of the floated elements.

to place an element in the center you must make it a block, with a static width and `margin:0 auto;`

The overflow is there so that the elements that float don't overflow :)

Comment: Thank you! So would not using lists be better?

Comment: there now its a list, and i added the 3 choices you wanted in the center, you just have to be careful to set the center size correctly